# Softening nougat candy

Tags: candy

Is there a way to soften nougat candy (Brach's peppermint)?  I live in a dry climate , have had them for a year, and don't want to break any teeth.  On the other hand, I don't want to throw them away.

Answer (score 2):

If you put them in a humid environment they'll absorb moisture.

If you have a deep enough bowl with a lid, put a glass of water in the middle and surround the glass with the candies.  Keep the lidded bowl in a room-temperature place for a few days where it won't be bumped (you don't want the water to spill...).  Stir the candies a few times to keep the moisture evenly distributed and to prevent them from sticking together.